# How to delete gradient marks on Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, adobe, gradient, markers

I am wondering how to delete gradient markers on Flash. For example, when I am working on a gradient in the color window, and hover my mouse over a marker, a plus sign appears, and if you click it, another marker surfaces. When I open a new file and use the gradient tool, it saved all of the markers I created.

How do I delete the markers at my discretion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse over the handle for a gradient marker, and drag it as you would if you were adjusting its location. Then simply drag it out of the color panel and release the mouse button. That's all there is to it!

Comment: thanks homey. I had a suspicion it what a simple answer like that.